# How to pipe a process' output to logger command and to head command?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, pipe

What I'm trying to do is:

- Start a process that outputs text continously
- Pipe that output to two commands:

  1. A logger script
  2. 'head' command, so I can save the first lines the initial process output.

What I tried so far (unsuccessfuly) is:

`./myProgram | tee > (myLogger log.txt) | head > firstLines.txt`

The problem is that the `myProgram` exits as soon as `head` is finished.

Even if I use `-i` in `tee` command, I can't get myProgram to keep running.

Since the logger may append the incoming text to an existing file, executing
`head log.txt > firstLines.txt`
won't work in this case.

Comment: Switch the order around. Use `>(...)` for `head` and the normal pipe for your logger?

Comment: This was my first guess as well, but I tried it and the problem persists.

Comment: Not so elegant solution:
Output to a temporary file, then append that temporary file to log.txt, then head temporary file, then remove temporary file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` as an alternative to do both:

```
./myProgram | 
    awk 'NR<=10{print > "firstLines.txt"} NR>10{close("firstLines.txt")} 1' > log.txt
```

Comment: Beat you by 8 seconds - what kept you? ;-)

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe:

```
yes | awk 'FNR<4 {print >>"file"; close("file")}  1' | more
```

where `yes` is your program, `file` is where you send the output of `head` to, and `more` is your logger.